# Is the sum $\sum_{d\mid n}\frac1{d+1}$ never integral?

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-functions

Recall that a positive integer $n$ is a perfect number if and only if 
$$\frac{\sigma(n)}n=\sum_{d\mid n}\frac1d=2.$$

QUESTION: Is my following conjecture true?

**Conjecture**. (i) We have $\sum_{d\mid n}\frac1{d+1}\not\in\mathbb Z$ for all $n=1,2,3,\ldots$. Moreover, for any positive integers $k$ and $m$, all the numbers
$$\sum_{d\mid n}\frac1{(d+m)^k}\ \ (n=1,2,3,\ldots)$$
have pairwise distinct fractional parts, and none of them is an integer.

(ii) For any integer $k>1$, all the numbers
$$\sum_{d\mid n}\frac1{d^k}\ \ (n=1,2,3,\ldots)$$
have pairwise distinct fractional parts.

I formulated this conjecture in October 2015 on the basis of my computation.
Your comments are welcome!

Comment: http://oeis.org/A057643 tabulates "Least common multiple of all $(k+1)$'s, where the $k$'s are the positive divisors of $n$."

Comment: Wouldn't this follow from the coprimality of  $ d+1 $ and  $ n+1 $?

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN It will, but these numbers are not necessarily coprime: take $n=9$, $d=3$.

Comment: Sure, but their radical will differ.

Comment: Informally, denoting by  $m_{k}(n) $ the common denominator of the numbers  $ 1/(d+k) $ when  $ d $ runs over the divisors of  $ n $, one should have  $\omega( m_{0}(n))=\omega(n)$ and  $\omega(m_{k}(n))\gg \tau(n) $ whenever  $ (n,k)=1 $.

Comment: In 2015 I checked $\sum_{d\mid n}\frac1{d+1}\not\in\mathbb Z$ for all $n\le2\times10^5$ and found no counterexample.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN This is still false! Take $d=3, n=15$

Answer (score -1):

For a given set of primes $Q=\{q_1,\dots,q_k\}$, to each prime $p\not\in Q$ we may associate the lattice
$$
L=L_{q_1,\dots,q_k,p}=\{(a_1,\dots,a_k)\in\mathbb{Z}^k: \prod_{i=1}^kq_i^{a_i}\equiv 1 \bmod p\}.
$$
and the coset
$$
H_m=H_{m;q_1,\dots,q_k,p}=\{(a_1,\dots,a_k)\in\mathbb{Z}^k: \prod_{i=1}^kq_i^{a_i}\equiv -m \bmod p\}.
$$
Then for all $n$ of the form
$$
n=\prod_{i=1}^kq_i^{e_i},
$$
$e_i>0$ for all $1\leq i\leq k$, if there exists a prime $p$ such that the box
$$
E_n=\{(a_1,\dots,a_k)\in\mathbb{Z}^k: 0\leq a_i\leq e_i, \mbox{for all }1\leq i\leq k\},
$$
intersects $H_m$ at exactly one element, (thus exactly one divisor $d$ of $n$ satisfies $p|(d+m)$), such $n$ satisfies
$$
\sum_{d|n}\frac{1}{d+m}\not\in\mathbb{Z}.
$$

Comment: It is not a problem to find $n$ such that the sum in question is not an integer. The problem is to show that it is *never* an integer.